# How to pass client Locale to remote EJB Bean via JNDI

Tags: java, jsf, ejb, bean-validation, ear

I have a problem regarding the localization of custom bean validation exceptions like `ConstraintViolationException` that are thrown at remote EJB Beans.

The JSF web application uses german locale and calls remote EJB Beans of an EAR that runs at englisch default locale. When a bean validation exceptions is thrown they are created using english locale.

Is there a way to pass the client locale to the remote bean (transaction) like defining it in JNDI lookup?

At client I extract the messages like:

```
final ConstraintViolationException cve = (ConstraintViolationException) e;

for (final ConstraintViolation<?> cv : cve.getConstraintViolations())
    context.addMessage(null, FacesMessageUtils.getMessage(context, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, cv.getMessage()));
```

Comment: This will strongly depend on how you have separated your modules, and which server you are using:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247689/pass-default-application-context-to-remote-ejb-anonymously

Comment: Thanks for the link. Will investigate the Interceptor option when i have more time.

Comment: I posted an possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085247/how-to-set-locale-in-bean-validation/44686346#44686346